# Searching MySQL database using PHP explode function to split keywords for individual search

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I am not very experienced in PHP and this is a cut & paste job iv gathered from numerous sources.

I want to be able to type in search box words example "tree website html" and search my database for "tree" "website" and "html" individually and show results, my code works BUT only if all words are in my database. So for example, if somewhere in my database I have the words "tree" and "website" but DONT have the word "html", if I search "tree website html" my search wont yield any results, but if I search "tree website" it will show results.

Can someone help me please and fix my code so if it dosent find a keyword it skips to the next one and shows results. Iv been messing about with this for days and I cant get it right cheers in advance

```
// Build SQL Query for each keyword entered
foreach ($trimmed_array as $trimm){
// EDIT HERE and specify your table and field names for the SQL query
// MySQL "MATCH" is used for full-text searching. Please visit mysql for         
details.
$query = "SELECT * , MATCH (message) AGAINST ('".$trimm."') AS score FROM     
mybbod_posts WHERE MATCH (message) AGAINST ('+".$trimm."') ORDER BY score DESC";

 // Execute the query to  get number of rows that contain search kewords
 $numresults=mysql_query ($query);
 $row_num_links_main =mysql_num_rows ($numresults);

 //If MATCH query doesn't return any results due to how it works do a search using LIKE
 if($row_num_links_main < 1){
    $query = "SELECT *, tid as $tidd FROM mybbod_posts WHERE message LIKE     '%$trimm%' OR message LIKE '%$trimm%'  ORDER BY message DESC";
    $numresults=mysql_query ($query);
 $row_num_links_main1 =mysql_num_rows ($numresults);
 }

 // next determine if 's' has been passed to script, if not use 0.
 // 's' is a variable that gets set as we navigate the search result pages.
 if (empty($s)) {
     $s=0;
 }

  // now let's get results.
  $query .= " LIMIT $s,$limit" ;
  $numresults = mysql_query ($query) or die ( "Couldn't execute search, ensure all words are seperated by a MAXIMUM of 1 space" );
  $row= mysql_fetch_array ($numresults);
```

Comment: You start a for loop with `{` but there's no closing `}`. Try to post code without syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is, if I search "tree website html" it shows no results but if I search "tree website" it does show results